# Sitecore 9 Commerce Specify Sitecore IDs on Create Catalog

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am creating a catalog from code.

```
_createCatalogCommand.Process(context.CommerceContext, AcogConstants.CatalogName, "My Catalog");
```

Process works. However, if clean the environment and re-run the process, I get new SitecordIds. This means that I have to manually go into Sitecore and reset a number of values to point to the new catalog items. I do not see a way with the  CreateCatalogCommand or EditCatalogCommand to set the SitecoreId to a specific ID. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. This was very simple. Just needed to run persist entity after create command:

```
var category = await _createCategoryCommand.Process(context.CommerceContext, catalogId, categoryName, categoryDisplayName, description);

category.SitecoreId = SomeFunctionToGetSitecoreId();

await _persistEntityPipeline.Run(new PersistEntityArgument(category), context);
```